# How do I denote a measurement with a margin of error using ±?

Tags: notation

I am trying to express a quantity that is measured to be $\pu{0.75 mL}$, but could be anywhere between $\pu{0.7 mL}$ and $\pu{0.8 mL}$. Is this the correct way to do it?

$$\pu{0.75 mL} \pm \pu{0.05 mL}$$

Comment: $\pu{0.75 \pm 0.05 mL}$ typically means a standard deviation of $\pu{0.05 mL}$, not a hard limit of $\pu{\pm 0.05 mL}$.

Comment: @MaxW is right on the money: the notation most frequently means sample mean +/- one sample standard deviation, computed from N independent measurements. So degrees of freedom is N-1 and this information should get conveyed. I could add a lot to my answer, but the downvotes on the question mean it probably is not worth the effort. One more thing: the +/- term can reasonably convey hard limits in some cases, e.g., histogram bin center +/- ends of the histogram bin. Other possibilities are +/- half a confidence interval or a standard error. Context is everything.

Comment: I'd say it should be written what the interval means, everything else is in practice too ambiguous: I regularly meet situations where it's not clear whether it is the standard deviation across measurements or the standar error of the mean. Not to mention the rather official recommendation in @EdV's answer to report extended uncertainty.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX I fully agree with you and I was going to reference this paper (D. Coleman, J. Auses, N. Grams, “Regulation – From an industry perspective or Relationships between detection limits, quantitation limits, and significant digits”, Chemom. Intell. Lab. Syst. 37 (1997) 71-80.), where Coleman et al. cogently criticize the inadequacy of the typical x ± y notation. Sadly, we are still having to deal with these needlessly ambiguous matters.

Answer (score 6):

I strongly recommend looking at this: **QUAM:2012.P1** (*EURACHEM/CITAC Guide, “**Q**uantifying **U**ncertainty in **A**nalytical **M**easurement”, 3rd Ed., 2012., 141 pages.*) You can easily [find it online](https://www.eurachem.org/index.php/publications/guides/quam), for *free*, and it is all about quantifying uncertainties in measurements, though with an obvious focus on analytical chemistry-related measurements. As an example, the figure below shows the **QUAM** recommended way to report standard and expanded uncertainties:

> **9.3. Reporting standard uncertainty**
>
> **9.3.1.** When uncertainty is expressed as the combined standard uncertainty $u_c$ (that is, as a single standard deviation), the following form is recommended:
>
> > "(Result): $x$ (units) [with a] standard uncertainty of $u_c$ (units) [where standard uncertainty is as defined in the ISO/IEC Guide to the Expression of Uncertainty in Measurement and corresponds to one standard deviation.]"
>
> NOTE: The use of the symbol $\pm$ is not recommended when using standard uncertainty as the symbol is commonly associated with intervals corresponding to high levels of confidence.
>
> Terms in parentheses [] may be omitted or abbreviated as appropriate.
>
> EXAMPLE:
>
> - Total nitrogen: $\pu{3.52 g}/\pu{100 g}$
> - Standard uncertainty: $\pu{0.07 g}/\pu{100 g}$*
> - *Standard uncertainty corresponds to one
>     standard deviation.
>
> **9.4. Reporting expanded uncertainty**
>
> **9.4.1.** Unless otherwise required, the result *x* should be stated together with the expanded uncertainty $U$ calculated using a coverage factor $k=2$ (or as described in section 8.3.3.). The following form is recommended:
>
> > "(Result): $(x \pm U)$ (units)
> >
> > [where] the reported uncertainty is [an expanded uncertainty as defined in the International Vocabulary of Basic and General terms in metrology, 2nd ed., ISO 1993,] calculated using a coverage factor of 2, [which gives a level of confidence of approximately 95 %]"
>
> Terms in parentheses [] may be omitted or abbreviated as appropriate. The coverage factor should, of course, be adjusted to show the value actually used.
>
> EXAMPLE:
>
> - Total nitrogen: $(3.52 \pm 0.14)~\mathrm{g}/100~\mathrm{g}$*
> - *The reported uncertainty is an expanded uncertainty calculated using a coverage factor of 2 which gives a level of confidence of approximately 95 %.

This is from pages 30-31 of QUAM, referenced above. **CITAC** is the acronym for *Co-Operation on International Traceability In Analytical Chemistry*.

All that said, your notation is quite common, so no worries.